# Python aiopg lastrowid

Tags: python, postgresql, python-asyncio, aiopg

I'm using asyncio and aiopg and after INSERT execute I can't get lastrowid.

My code:

```
 async with aiopg.create_pool(self.connect, loop=self._loop) as pool:
      async with pool.acquire() as connect:
           async with connect.cursor() as cursor:
                await cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users(user_firstname,user_lastname) VALUES('Johan', 'Smith')")
                print(await cursor.lastrowid)
                print(' - - - ')
                pass
           pass
      pass
 pass
```

Execute worked, but lastrowid don't printed and next print too.

Same with fetchone() and fetchall(), if I executed SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

[`cursor.lastrowid`](http://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core.html#aiopg.Cursor.lastrowid) is a regular property, drop `await` before access to it.